# I cant use index of in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a shopping cart. When I click an Item it pushes to localStorage
but second time when I click it should be removed,  so I need the indexOf the Item.

My localStorage is an Array of Object, but when I want to get Index of my Item it returns `-1`. what is the problem ?

```js
addToShoppingCard(e, service) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let oldItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('basket')) || [];
  let parent = e.target.parentNode;
  parent.classList.add('added');
  let child = parent.childNodes;
  child[0].classList.toggle('hideChoose');
  if (child[0].classList.contains('hideChoose')) {
    let index = oldItems.indexOf(service);
    console.log(oldItems);
    console.log(service);
    console.log(index);
  } else {
    oldItems.push(service);
    sessionStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` `oldItems` and `service`?

Comment: `indexOf` checks for strict equality `===` which means that if `service` is not a primitive (string, number, etc.), `indexOf` will return `-1` because `oldItems` cannot contain `service` it may contain an object that has the same properties and values as this object but not this object itself.

Comment: If `let oldItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('basket')) || [];` returns an array of Strings or Numbers, you just need to check, whether the service you are adding is of String or Number type. Otherwise, check that the storage really has that items saved.

Comment: What are the console logs saying?

Comment: the array of objects wont be equal to a service object. they dont share the same memory location. if you want to find the index by a value in your `service` you could use `.findIndex( (serviceObj) => serviceObj.someValue === service.someValue)`. This is assuming its an object since you said `My localStorage is an Array of Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, as Titus said, you need to use another way to get the index of the object. Let's guess that a service has an ID attribute, then try using this code:

```js
addToShoppingCard(e, service) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let oldItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('basket')) || [];
  let parent = e.target.parentNode;
  parent.classList.add('added');
  let child = parent.childNodes;
  child[0].classList.toggle('hideChoose');
  if (child[0].classList.contains('hideChoose')) {
    let index = oldItems.findIndex(s => s.id === service.id);
    console.log(oldItems);
    console.log(service);
    console.log(index);
  } else {
    oldItems.push(service);
    sessionStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
  }
}
```

Or if you are searching by service it's `name`, just replace `findIndex` predicate function to `s => s.name === service.name`.

That should work